# Turning floated elements into stacked elements on small screens

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have 3 boxes that are currently floated left of each other,

https://jsfiddle.net/2owu0k7s/

When viewing on a smartphone I want the width of the boxes to be near full screen, and the height of each box to be the same height has the viewport. Is this possible to do?

I have tried doing this within a media query,

```
.box {
    float:none;
    width:95%;
    margin:0 auto 20px;
    height:95%;
}
```

But on my iphone 6s I can still see more than 1 box and 5% of another.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2owu0k7s/1/
Hopefully this will work.

Comment: I see no media query in either your question nor your fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When viewing on a smartphone I want the width of the boxes to be near full screen, and the height of each box to be the same height has the viewport. Is this possible to do?

With a media query and flexbox it is possible (and quite simple, in fact). Here's the smartphone view:

```css
body { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid red;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

### [Revised Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2owu0k7s/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.box {
  width:350px;
  height:50vh;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
  .box {
    float:none;
    width:95%;
    margin:0 auto 20px;
    height:96vh;
    }
}
```

Write an media query and
Give the height measurements using 'vh' -vertical height.
100vh means full screen-height.